# Proper error handling with NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, bugsnag

I have a very basic migration code that looks like this. It removes the table, creates the table, and seeds it with some data.

```
this.knex.schema.dropTable(this.tableName)
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
.then(() => {
    this.knex.schema.createTable(this.tableName, function(table) {
        table.increments("id").primary();
        table.string("name");
        table.integer("parent_id").unsigned().default(0);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .then(() => {
        this.categories.forEach((category) => {
            Category.create(category)
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
            .then((category) => console.log(category.get("name") + " seeded."))
        });
    });
});
```

As you may notice, there is 3x `.catch((err) => console.log(err))` chain on the code.

Right now I have Bugsnag integrated to my application and I want to make sure I properly log all the exceptions/errors on Bugsnag so I can fix all the bugs. However, right now all I can do is to log them into console. Even worse, I repeat myself and duplicating the logic in each `catch` block.

I'm thinking about doing something like this:

```
.catch((err) => ErrorHandler.add(err))

class ErrorHandler {

    add(err) {
        // Notify Bugsnag
        // Log it to console
    }

}
```

That abrings another issue. What if I forget adding `catch` methods... then it still won't work.

Thought about doing something like this, too:

```
// Change exception behaviour so whenever they are called, they raise an  `onException` event
app.listen("onException", (err) => {
    // Notify Bugsnag
    // Log error to console
});
```

this way I can catch all errors and DRY my code, but I'm not sure if Node supports hooking exceptions.

What would you do in my case and what kind of approach should I take? I want to make sure all errors are properly sent to Bugsnag.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, does `this.knex.schema.createTable` return a promise? (If not you can always convert it to return a promise) If so you could write this logic in a little bit cleaner way, like:

```
this.knex.schema.dropTable(this.tableName)
.then((...) => {
  ...
  return this.knex.schema.createTable(...)
})
.then((...) => {
 ... // do whatever you are doing with table object
  return Promise.all( map and do whatever you are doing with categories)
})
.then(() => {
  // log that everything went well with seeding
})
.catch((err) => {
  // single catch block to handle errors from this promise chain
})
```

`Promise.all` will return rejected promise if any promise from array rejects, if you find that this not suite your needs, you can use `.reflect()` from bluebird (something that native promise support in node doesnt have, http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html)

Second, instead of console.log (console.error or whatever) you can consider to use something like bunyan, https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan

Third, in general you always needs to defend your app against `uncaughtException`, like

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  ...
})
```

> What if I forget adding catch methods

From my perspective that would be bug in code and you need to be aware of that.
It is same like you forget to handle error in callback, such as:

```
doSomething((err, data) => {
  // do something with data without checking against err
})
```

So same question could be asked, `What if I forget to check against err`, well to put it simply you are not handling errors. As a rule of thumb don't test only sunny day scenarios, like everything went well. Test against different scenarios in your code, including rainy day scenarios in which something will throw, ensure that you are handling it in a proper way.

Also there is one more thing from which you can benefit, you mentioned `Express` in your question. You can register global error handler that you need to define after all your routes such as:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  ...
})
```

With this, from any route you can pass your error via `return next(err)` to this handler (if some special error handling logic is not needed, specific to particular endpoint), ensuring one place from which you can handle your errors such as log error and return `500` with some message or whatever. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. If createTable doesn't return a promise, how can I convert it to return a promise? Also, what exactly is Bluebird and how does it understand the completion of an array map? Right now it is just a bunch of different `save(...).then(...)` promises.  I guess I must read about promises sometime soon. Is there anything you can suggest about this?

Comment: Your guess is correct, you should get familiar with promises first, something that can really help: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: I readed it. It answers most of my questions. However, I'm not sure how can I promisify this one: `this.knex.schema.createTable`. Also, in the future, if I need to promisify something that doesn't return a promise, how can I do it? Override the method and return `Promise.something()`?